# escape , in jsfcljs javascript function

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I need to escape the comma[,] from `jsfcljs` function. My function looks like this:

```
if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['frmWorkProduct'],
'frmWorkProduct:attachmentList1:1:j_id_jsp_1358599777_276,frmWorkProduct:attachmentList1:1:j_id_jsp_1358599777_276,
fileName,test,.xlsx,attachId,1355462000554','');}return false
```

here ...`fileName,test,.xlsx,attachId`... where `fileName` contains `','` which needs to be escaped because it takes `test,.xlsx` as `test` and `.xlsx` as parameter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Mojarra 1.2 which is almost 5 years ago already reported as [issue 724](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-724) and already fixed in 1.2_09 (under the covers, the fix was to pass those parameters as a JS object instead of as a commaseparated string).

So, if you upgrade to at least Mojarra 1.2_09 (it's already at [1.2_15](http://java.net/downloads/javaserverfaces/release/1.2_15/mojarra-1.2_15-b01-FCS-binary.zip) for years now), then your problem should disappear (and more; there were pretty a lot of bugfixes and performance enhancements in the later versions). Try to not stick with heavily outdated versions for too long :)